# Form API adds word "edit" in ID of every Form element

Tags: forms

FORM API adds word "edit" before the id of any form element. When I have to use the element in JS  I have to add "edit" before element id.

Example if I have element $form['curdate'] then in drupal_add_js('#edit-curdate');

Why so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal adds `edit` to denote that the element is an input element. It helps to identify form elements through CSS, and reduces the possibility of ID clashes with other elements on the page.

In case you're interested, this is done in the [`form_builder()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_builder/7) function...and there's no easy way to override it system-wide.

You can easily override it for individual form elements though if it's bothering you:

```
$form['element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Some title',
  // ...
  '#id' => drupal_html_id('my-new-id')
);
```

Comment: Thanks....I am trying to use Jquery_ui datepicker but its not working in Drupal 7. so I thought the error might be due to JS using datapicker

Comment: The UI datepicker works great for me in Drupal 7, are you trying to include it in a custom form? If so what's your code?

Comment: Yes I am trying to use it custom form module. jquery_ui_add(array('ui.datepicker'));
  drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){$("input#edit-curdate").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});});','inline');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_ui') . "/ui.datepicker.css", 'module');                                                   $form['curdate']=array( '#type'=>'textfield','#title'=>'Date*);

Comment: Try: `$form['element'] = array('#type' => 'date_popup', '#title' => 'Date', '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y');`. That works perfectly for me. The date module has that `date_popup` widget built in so you don't need to add any CSS/JS yourself, Drupal will do it all for you

Comment: I have installed Date module with all features.but following errors are displaying...     Notice: Undefined index: #id in theme_date_popup() (line 663 of D:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\date\date_popup\date_popup.module).
    Warning: Missing argument 1 for myform_data_entry_form() in myform_data_entry_form() (line 28 of D:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\myform\myform.module).
    Warning: Missing argument 2 for myform_data_entry_form() in myform_data_entry_form() (line 28 of D:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\myform\myform.module).

Comment: @Dharmender Please keep the comments about the currently asked question. Using a date popup is a different question.